# Issue On MYSQL Query Which Throwing Invalid Use Group Function Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I just need an help on making an query work.

I wanted To get the records for an all users whose total cdr seconds is >= 2400 (40 minutes)

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration)) AS secsUsed 
FROM cdr 
WHERE SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration))>=2400 
GROUP BY ownerpin 
ORDER BY secsUsed DESC
```

i found that aggregate function usage like above will not work!

is there any way that i could get the logic work !!

Comment: What error do you receive? Columns in the GROUP BY have to be SELECTed.

Comment: Receiving Error 1111: Invalid use of group function, I Just wanted the cdr seconds

Comment: the title may looks simillar but the query problem is different , i checked with other question of same title too, since i was not able to find any solution, i have posted

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition from `WHERE` to `HAVING` clause:

```
select ownerpin,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration)) as secsUsed 
from cdr 
group by ownerpin 
HAVING SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration))>=2400 
order by secsUsed desc ;
```

Comment: Thanks , This query works!!! also i have another issue,
check the below query 

select SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration)) as secsUsed ,cdr.ownerpin, user.userid, DATEDIFF(now(),user.dateadded) as daydiff from cdr inner join (select ownerpin,userid,dateadded,is_active,plan_type from user where user.is_active =true and user.plan_type like '%trial%' ) as user on cdr.ownerpin =user.ownerpin where DATEDIFF(now(),dateadded) >=14 or  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration))  >=2400 group by cdr.ownerpin order by secsUsed desc;

Comment: now i wanted to perform two condition that is either the user's has passed 14 days or his/her cdr minutes exceeds 40 minutes

can u help  Error 1111: Invalid use of group function

this also throwing

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the second query !!! Any Help!!

Comment: i Justed wanted to make the following condition work 

where DATEDIFF(now(),dateadded) >=14 or SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cdr.duration)) >=2400